# ScrollTop goes to the wrong top

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion, offset, scrolltop

I have a list of items. When I click on one item (project) it opens (this is ok) and it scrolls to the top of the page (the wrong top!). The problem occurs when I have an opened item and I decide to open the one below: the top position is increased by the opened project height and the second project I click goes too far over the top.

Following the FIDDLE below: if I open *project1* and then I click on *project2*, this goes on the wrong top. Same if I try to open any project below another opened one.

**JS**

```
$('.accordion-section-title').on('click', function () {
    var idName = $(this).attr('id');

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#" + idName).offset().top
    }, 500);
});
```

Here's the [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/8edjgqcd/)

Comment: What if you replace `scrollTop: $("#" + idName).offset().top - 10}, 500)` with `scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 10}, 500)`?

Comment: It doesn't change, I think the items are just fine with the scrolling itself: it's the changing top position I want to get rid of.

Comment: Oh on a second look, I believe the problem is caused by the window calculating the scroll position with the accordion sections open. When they are closed the height of the contents is altered and thus the window scrolls to the wrong Y position.

Comment: Exaclty, I don't know how to get all the item to stop at the right top without the scroll calculating also the space of the open item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be the `.slideUp()` and `.slideDown()` methods are animated at the same time the window is scrolling. By the time the window has scrolled to the right Y coordinate, the accordion sections' heights have been altered, thus causing the window to end up in the wrong position.

I'm sure there are other ways to accomplish correct scroll positions, but my first thought was to store the initial Y positions once the page is loaded. This can be done this way:

```
$('.accordion-section-title').each(function() {
  $(this).data('ypos', $(this).offset().top)
})
```

Each `.accordion-section-title` element will have its Y position stored in a data attribute called `ypos`. Later when you scroll the window, don't scroll to the elements *position*, but rather to its *stored initial position*. In other words, change `scrollTop: $("#" + idName).offset().top` to `scrollTop: $("#" + idName).data('ypos')`. Put together with your code it will look like the following:

```
$('.accordion-section-title').on('click', function(e) {
  var idName = $(this).attr('id');
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#" + idName).data('ypos') - 10
  }, 500);
});
```

You can see how it plays out in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4hfk7af3/7/)

Comment: This is the perfect solution I was looking for! Thank you very much for this. I don't want to seem pretentious, but do you know how could I open the first project when the page loads? 
Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I’m glad it worked for you! :o) I’m not at my desk right now, so unable to provide you with a working code snippet. What I would do is to apply a CSS class to the first accordion to have it displayed as open. Then remove this class when another section is activated. Or you could trigger a click with jquery. E.g. `$('.my-first-accordion-title').trigger("click")`.

Comment: Alright you definitely made my week! As a beginner in jQuery I'm starting to  feel good. I used `$("div.accordion div:first-child .accordion-section-title").trigger('click');});` in order to always get the last project opened.